# How to stop Tomcat server launched from an Eclipse Gradle Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, gradle

I'm running through a tutorial from http://spring.io about RESTful webservices.
I wanted to be able to launch my web project from Eclipse as a Gradle build (*Run As => Gradle Build...*) and then stop it when I'm done testing it.
I know how to start it, but I just can't get it to stop without quitting Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite).

Any Suggestions?

Comment: How are you starting Tomcat? Are you using the [Gradle Tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin)?

Comment: If Eclipse is using the Tooling API of Gradle, it's not possible directly. See this reported issue: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1539. This is also an issue in Netbeans, but I think IntelliJ has a different technique for launching  from gradle and is better able to shut it down. I would use a custom task as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To borrow from the [Gradle Tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) documentation, just do this:

```
ext {
    tomcatStopPort = 8081
    tomcatStopKey = 'stopKey'
}

task doTomcatRun(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.TomcatRun) {
    stopPort = tomcatStopPort
    stopKey = tomcatStopKey
    daemon = true
}

task doTomcatStop(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.TomcatStop) {
    stopPort = tomcatStopPort
    stopKey = tomcatStopKey
}

task someTask(type: SomeGradleTaskType) {
    //do stuff
    dependsOn doTomcatRun
    finalizedBy doTomcatStop
}
```

In this example, `someTask` is a Gradle task that you execute where Tomcat is started before the task runs and Tomcat is stopped after the task completes.

If you prefer something more manual, then simply configure and then run the `tomcatStop` task via Eclipse:

```
tomcatStop {
        stopPort = 8090
        stopKey = 'foo'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I humbly suggest you using gradle "jetty" plugin instead. Consider:

a) it supports jettyRun, jettyRunWar and jettyStop tasks.

b) it uses jetty 6 and, therefore, is compatible with servlet-api 2.5 (the equivalent version of tomcat is 6).

If you are not satisfied with too old jetty/servlet-api, feel free trying "gretty" plugin (which I wrote) - it supports jetty 7/8/9 and servlet-api 2.5/3.0.1/3.1.0. Gretty plugin is available in maven central and on github: https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty . The documentation is also provided on github.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle`

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopPort = 8081
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stopKey'
```